# SqlClient Traces on Azure

Tags: azure, trace, sqlclient

How do I enable and view SqlClient traces on Azure?
I have a web app hosted on Azure and it uses SqlClient.
I know that we can use XPerf/PerfView to collect and view traces. But I am not sure how to use it when the web app is hosted on Azure app service.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web app you could use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) to track calls made using SqlClient. These calls are autocollected as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies). Do mind that, in order for full sql query tracking, you will need to opt-in for this feature as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query):

> `services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module. EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });`

As a bonus you get detailed insights regarding your apps workings, performance and failures.